# json.stringify is not calling toJson on all objects under main object

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In IE 11, calling Stringify on my objects is not recursively calling toJson on all object in the tree. I have a custom toJson function

```
Object.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  if (!(this.constructor.name == "Array")) {
    if (JSON._serialized[this._id]) {
      if (this.material) {
        return {
          name: this.name,
          material: this.material
        };
      } else {
        return { referenceId: this._id };
      }
    }
    var json = this.toJSONProperties();
    json._id = this._id;
    json._runID = this._runID;
    json._className = this.constructor.name;
    JSON._serialized[this._id] = true;
    return json;
  } else {
    return this;
  }
}
```

This works in chrome, firefox and safari, but in IE 11 this toJson function only gets called on the top level object when I call `var json = JSON.stringify(object);`
The idea im working with is have toJson be a generic function on all classes, then have `var json = this.toJSONProperties();` on the specific classes i want to convert. Any Ideas why this only fails in IE?

**Update**

I fixed the problem. It turns out that `this.constructor.name` doesn't work in IE.
Changing it to `this.constructor.toString().match(/function (.{1,})\(/)[1]` fixes the error.

Comment: what's the def for toJSONProperties() ?

Comment: What is puzzling me is why it's working on other browsers: if the root object has a `toJSON` method, it should be called and no other attribute should be taken in consideration

Comment: Here is the toJSONProperties on the top class.
   `Deck.prototype.toJSONProperties = function() {
     return {
       _components: this._components
     }
   };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.constructor.name` doesn't work in IE. Changing it to `this.constructor.toString().match(/function (.{1,})\(/)[1]` fixes the issue.